# Palindrome function in python

Tags: python, function, text-files, palindrome

Hey so my assignment is:

palindrome = reverse    is  the same    as  the itself, e.g.
“doggod” is a   plaindrome), scan   a   file     line   by  line     find   the palindrome  in  it  and 
return  a   list     with   palindrome  found.

This is what I have so far:

```
def find_palidrome(word):
    if len(word) < 1:
        return True
    else:
        if word[0] == word[-1]:
            return find_palidrome(word[1:-1])
        else:
            return False
def fileInput(alice.txt):
    f = open(alice.txt,'r')
    line = f.readline().strip()
    while line != '':
        if(find_palidrome(line)):
            print(line)
        else:
            print("No palindromes found")
        line = f.readline().strip()
    file.close()
```

Its not working and keeps saying syntax error IDK whats wrong.
Can someone please help!!?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware that python is indentation driven? Either you failed posting your source, or you actually have an indentation problem.

Comment: Oh yeah i messed up posting it this is what it shouldve said:

Comment: If that is what your code actually looks like you are going to have lots of problems. Please edit your post to make it match what the code looks like in your editor. Edit post don't try post in a comment.

Comment: what is the full text of your syntax error ?

Comment: def find_palidrome(word):
    if len(word) < 1:
        return True
    else:
        if word[0] == word[-1]:
            return find_palidrome(word[1:-1])
        else:
            return False
def fileInput(alice.txt):
    f = open(alice.txt,'r')
    line = f.readline().strip()
    while line != '':
        if(find_palidrome(line)):
            print(line)
        else:
            print("No palindromes found")
        line = f.readline().strip()
    file.close()

Comment: ^ Edit your original question.

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax and it highlights the def in my def fileinput

Comment: also why cant i post my original code without the indentations getting all jacked up?

Comment: I think the issue is the `alice.txt` parameter.

Comment: reddit.com/r/learnpython maybe a more appropriate resource for this type of question.

Comment: ok thats ^^^ what my code looks like sorry i messed up posting

Answer (score 1):

This is a much simpler way to find a palindrome of a word:

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    return word == word[::-1]
```

And then to read the file:

```
def check_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if is_palindrome(line):
                print(line)
            else:
                print("No palindromes found")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f_name = input('Enter a file path')
    check_file(f_name)
```

As others have pointed out the problem was not passing in your file name as a string. In the code I have posted the file name is entered as a string by default from the `input()` built in. Wrapping everything up in an `if __name == '__main__'` block makes it so that you can import these functions into other programs with out running the whole script.

Comment: +1 for me (I don't get why you got -1). I did the same code, except I kept the default value for `file_name`.